# How to add a symbol before every section but not before every subsection

Tags: sectioning, numbering, titles

(I'll use `$+$` for the "symbol" in question).

What I want to achieve:

> +1. Section
>
> Lorem ipsum
>
> 1.1. Subsection
>
> Lorem ipsum

That is,

- Have every section name after a `$+$` and the section number
- Have every subsection name after the section number and the subsection number (no `$+$` before the section number).

I'm using a report type document and I currently have a code that uses

```
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries}{\LARGE\thesection}{1em}{\LARGE #1}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{$+ \,$\arabic{section}}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\bfseries}{\large\thesubsubsection}{1em}{\large #1}
```

which compiles documents of the form

> +1. Section
>
> Lorem ipsum
>
> +1.1. Subsection
>
> Lorem ipsum

Not the desired result.

How can I make my document look like the first example?

Comment: Are you using `titlesec`?

Comment: @Bernard , yes, I'm using `titlesec`.

Comment: In this case, add the  symbol at the relevant place of `\titleformat{\section}{…}`

Comment: @Bernard, well, that was pretty easy lol. Thanks :)

Comment: It depends on whether you want the + also when you reference to sections with `\ref`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution, which does not require loading any external packages, has the added advantage of not messing up the ability to create cross-references to section-level headers via the standard LaTeX `\label`-`\ref` approach. (A command such as `\renewcommand{\thesection}{$+ \,$\arabic{section}}` does affect how cross-references look -- probably not the intended outcome, though.) Instead, it relies on some code I learned about years ago, when I studied the book "The LaTeX Companion".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

% See p. 21 of "The LaTeX Companion", 2nd ed.
\makeatletter 
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}%    default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}% enable individual control
\newcommand\section@cntformat{$+$\thesection.\quad}    % section level 
\newcommand\subsection@cntformat{\thesubsection.\quad} % subsection level 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Section} \label{sec:uno}
Lorem ipsum.
\subsection{Subsection}
A cross-reference to section \ref{sec:uno}.
\end{document}
```